# Passing variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables

I'm new to C#. I thought I knew a bit of C# but clearly not.

As an example I'm using a very plain form with a button and a custom textbox. Clicking on the button should give me the content of the custom textbox, but I'm getting

> Error  CS0103  The name 'tb' does not exist in the current context

I have tried all possible options provided but with no luck.

When I use a static textbox (named `tb`) from the toolbox then it works without any errors. Below is my code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();

    tb.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    tb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(600, 430);
    tb.Multiline = true;

    panel2.Controls.Add(tb);
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
}
```

I have tried to search Google and Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: `I'm not sure what to search for` - try "variable scope".

Comment: The declaration of the button tb: TextBox tb = new TextBox(); is locale to the method Form1_Load. You must declare tb in the class as global

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# referencing a variable from another method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301197/c-sharp-referencing-a-variable-from-another-method)

Comment: When you receive error message like these just search for the exception message with your identifier omitted.  E.g. searching for `Error CS0103 The name does not exist in the current context` brings up a load of answers to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem of scope. You are declaring `tb` in your method, so outside the method it doesn't exist. You want to declare `tb` outside the method in the class itself:

```
TextBox tb;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb = new TextBox();

    tb.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    tb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(600, 430);
    tb.Multiline = true;

    panel2.Controls.Add(tb);
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `tb` variable is defined in the context of `Form_Load()`. Then it is added to the panel, then it goes out of scope. You need to find another way to get access to your text box... for example by making it a member variable of the class.