# How to assign a variable in one method and change/use it in another method?

Tags: c#, variables

What changes do I have to make for the x and z variables to retain the values they are assigned in the Assign method? I have only recently started learning C# for college after learning C++ for 2 years in school so this is very confusing to me.

```
class Program
{
    static void Assign(int x, int z)
    {
        x = 3;
        z = 2;
    }

    static void Sum(int x, int z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + z);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        int x = 0, z = 0;
        Assign(x,z);
        Sum(x,z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely they covered variable scope or passing arguments, no?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You could declare them in a higher scope or pass them by ref.

Comment: What would you do in C++? You'd make them private member variables. But in C# you'd call them fields. What were you doing in C++ for those two years you spent learning it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# referencing a variable from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301197/c-sharp-referencing-a-variable-from-another-method)  (and countless others)

Comment: The only things we were shown about C# were console input/output, if statements and for/while loops in the first lecture.

Comment: There isnt a *book*? Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Another option is top use tuple deconstruction in c# 7.0:  `static (int, int) Assign() { return (3, 2); }`  Then in the calling code:  `(int x, int y) = Assign();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood how variable scopes work. The `x` in `Assign` is *not* the same as `x` in `Main`. This is because in C#, `int` is passed by value (this is the same as C++, BTW).

You probably meant to mark the variables in `Assign` as [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref):

```
class Program
{
    static void Assign(ref int x, ref int z)
    {
        x = 3;
        z = 2;
    }

    static void Sum(int x, int z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + z);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        int x = 0, z = 0;
        Assign(x, z);
        Sum(x, z);
    }
}
```

Note the this is not recommended, because now `Assign` has side-effects. This is better:

```
class Program
{
    static void PrintSum(int x, int z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x + z);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        PrintSum(3, 2);
    }
}
```

For more background, I would suggest looking at [the difference between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

Comment: +1 but I don't think the OP "probably" meant to use ref at all, they are just a confused beginner; your second example is the only one that makes sense.

Comment: To me, this question looks like homework about reference-vs-value, so I answered it that way.

Comment: Another option is top use tuple deconstruction in c# 7.0:  `static (int, int) Assign() { return (3, 2); }`  Then in the calling code:  `(int x, int y) = Assign();`