# Can't use variable declared in Form1() in Button1_Click()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scope

I'm learning C# and got confronted with a very simple problem in other langages that make me mad here... I must be missing something obvious but after a couple hours looking and trying solutions, here I come :p

I'm making a program simulating a Beehive management.
In the Form1() declaration I initialize 2 variables, one array of Worker objects and a Queen object that contains the array of workers bee :

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[4];
        workers[0] = new Worker(new string[] { "Nectar Collector", "Honey Manufacturing" });
        workers[1] = new Worker(new string[] { "Egg Care", "Baby Bee Tutoring" });
        workers[2] = new Worker(new string[] { "Hive Maintenance", "Sting Patrol" });
        workers[3] = new Worker(new string[] { "Nectar Collector", "Honey Manufacturing", "Egg Care", "Baby Bee Tutoring", "Hive Maintenance", "Sting Patrol" });

        Queen queen = new Queen(workers);
    }
```

Next, my "Button1" is used to assign a work to a bee, using the Queen object declared in the Form1().
Obviously, it's not in the same scope since "queen" is declared in Form1().
So I get an error in this code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(***queen***.AssignWork(workerBeeJob.Text, (int)shifts.Value))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The job '" + workerBeeJob.Text + "` will be done in");
        }
```

"The name "queen" doesn't exist in the actual context".

And if I try to instanciate a Queen object in the scope of my class (simply using "Queen queen;"...), I can't pass him a Workers array nor use her since her workers's array is null.
If I try to instanciante an array of workers, it seems to work to create him ("Worker[] workers = New Worker[4];") but not to instanciate his values ("workers[0] = ...."), and at this moment, all my code goes nicely underlined in red while the same code works like a charm in Form1() method.

So here are the questions :

- Why do we have to initialize components in the Form1() if we can't use them in another method ?
- Why do I get a looooot of errors if I do the initialisation of Workers's array in class Form1 directly ?
- And obviously, how do I can use my Queen and her Worker array in the event listener ?

Sorry if i'm not clear and for the lot of question for a problem that simple. I have read many posts, in particular this post : [C# referencing a variable from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301197/c-sharp-referencing-a-variable-from-another-method) but it don't answer my problem.

Comment: Because that variable is defined within the scope of the constructor `public Form1()` and therefore can only be used there. Declare it outside to give it a global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*>> And obviously, how do I can use my Queen and her Worker array in the event listener?*

You defined the queen variable as local variable. This means when it goes out of scope, it will be no longer available. You need to define the queen variable as field.

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    private Queen _queen;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[4];
        workers[0] = new Worker(new string[] { "Nectar Collector", "Honey Manufacturing" });
        workers[1] = new Worker(new string[] { "Egg Care", "Baby Bee Tutoring" });
        workers[2] = new Worker(new string[] { "Hive Maintenance", "Sting Patrol" });
        workers[3] = new Worker(new string[] { "Nectar Collector", "Honey Manufacturing", "Egg Care", "Baby Bee Tutoring", "Hive Maintenance", "Sting Patrol" });

        _queen = new Queen(workers);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_queen.AssignWork(workerBeeJob.Text, (int)shifts.Value))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The job '" + workerBeeJob.Text + "` will be done in");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i'd prefix my fields with an `_`. This isn't required, but it's improving readability. This way i always know that i'm dealing with a field instead of a local.

---

*>> Why do we have to initialize components in the Form1() if we can't use them in another method?*

The `InitializeComponent();` is defined in the `Form1.designer.cs` file and is generated by the form designer. You can't define two (the same signature) constructors in partial classes. So they implemented a method which does the initialization for the controls. The controls aren't accessable before the InitializeComponent.

---

*>> Why do I get a looooot of errors if I do the initialisation of Workers's array in class Form1 directly?*

You cannot add executable code in a class directly. It needs to be in a method/property

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply.

Like I said, I already tried to instanciate in global scope using :

`public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Queen queen;`

But it doesn't work since my Worker[] is null. And I can't instantiate him without getting all my code going wrong...

Comment: Ha ! Ok got it ! I was creating a new instance of Queen in the Form1() instead of using the global one.

Thanks for answering all my questions ! Have a good day :)