# Pass variable to another method

Tags: c#

I am here again with my stupid questions again about basics of C#. I like to learn while creating something I am interested at, maybe this is the problem.

Here I am trying to get int variable `CompanySearchID` from `SearchForCompanyAndCreateIfNotFound` to `FilesAction`. So

I am getting correct value for `CompanySearchID` but how to pass it to another method? I have went through some examples, but none of them were helpful. For example this one: [C# referencing a variable from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301197/c-sharp-referencing-a-variable-from-another-method).
Using example from this question I am getting errors pointing at `FilesAction(MCountry, MTopicShort, MCompany, MDeadline);` and I can't figure out how to connect all three methods together. Can anybody give me a hint?

Here is my code (Note! comment "instead of 4 should be CompanySearchID"):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

                    ...                        

                    FilesAction(MCountry, MTopicShort, MCompany, MDeadline);

                    ...
        }
    }

   public static void FilesAction(string MCountry, string MTopicShort, string MCompany, DateTime MDeadline)
    {

                ...

                SearchForCompanyAndCreateIfNotFound(MCountry, MCompany);
                // I need to get CompanySearchID variable from below method SearchForCompanyAndCreateIfNotFound here so I can use it later in this method
                int total;
                total = CompanySearchID + 6;
                Console.WriteLine(total);
                // So I should get 12 in Console
                ...

            }
    }

    public static int SearchForCompanyAndCreateIfNotFound(string MCountry, string MCompany)
    {
            ...
            // I am performing some actions here and as an ouput I am getting a number to CompanySearchID
            int CompanySearchID = 6;
            return CompanySearchID;

            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `SetValue(...)`?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to do. Also add the error message you get and on which line of code you get it.

Comment: I have simplified my questions code, hopefully it is more understandable what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Wouldn't you simply need to do `var CompanySearchID = this. SearchForCompanyAndCreateIfNotFound (MCountry, MCompany)` as you are returning a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean save the return value of a method call?

```
int companySearchID = SearchForCompanyAndCreateIfNotFound(MCountry, MCompany);

isCompany.Value.SetValue(
    MFDataType.MFDatatypeLookup,  
    companySearchID
);
```

Comment: If you want clarification on the (rather unclear) question do write a comment!

Comment: This was correct solution to my problem! Thank you! Now I will know how to use this logic