# Property set in one method is returning null when retrieved from another method

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to refer a variable in different scopes i.e in a different method. I am doing this by using getter and setter but the variable in a different method is coming as null. I saw a related problem here but this too is not working [C# referencing a variable from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301197/c-sharp-referencing-a-variable-from-another-method). Here is my code:

```
private string FileName { get; set; }

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {                
        FileName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();        
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        FileName = FileName.Replace(extension, "");
        if (extension.ToLower()==".pdf")
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + FileName));
        }
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string saveLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/" + FileName + ".doc");
    Response.Clear();            
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;fileName" + Filename);
    Response.WriteFile(saveLocation);
    Response.End();
}
```

while I am running this the `FileName` is coming as `NULL`. Though it is a property and a class variable.
Another even is basically a logic for downloading a file at `saveLocation`. What I could be missing?

Comment: Each click is handled by a different instance of your page. You will need to persist the property in ViewState or Session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of these methods are called upon separate requests to your application, one for each button click. Each request will create a new instance of your page class, meaning the property will be re-initialized (in this case, the default value of `string`, which is `null`).

In order to keep the value around, you'll need to put it somewhere that can persist between requests but be distinct to the user. We have just such a place in the `Session` object.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {                
        string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();        
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        fileName = fileName.Replace(extension, "");
        if (extension.ToLower()==".pdf")
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName));
        }
        Session["UploadedFileName"] = fileName;
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Session["UploadedFileName"];
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
    {
        // you may want to throw and exception or display an error message here...
        // At minimum, don't try to send the file
        return;
    }

    string saveLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/" + fileName + ".doc");
    Response.Clear();            
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;fileName" + Filename);
    Response.WriteFile(saveLocation);
    Response.End();
}
```