# How to use an instantiated object from one method to another?

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have these two methods:

```
 public MessagesPage(ContactModel input)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            ConversationsList = new ObservableCollection<ConversationModel>();
            ContactModel ConversationPartner = new ContactModel();
            ConversationPartner = input;
            ...
        }
```

And the input which is the parameter in the method above, I also would like to use it in this method (they're in the same class)

```
 private async void Send()
        {
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string ID = guid.ToString();
            ConversationModel conversationObject = new ConversationModel()
            {
                id = ID,
                converseeID = dataClass.loggedInUser.uid,
                message = Message,
                created_at = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                    .Instance
                    .GetCollection("contacts")
                    .GetDocument(ConversationPartner.id)
                    .GetCollection("conversations")
                    .GetDocument(ID)
                    .SetDataAsync(conversationObject);
            Message = string.Empty;
        }
```

because as you can see, in .GetDocument, it needs the id of ConversationPartner. I would *get object reference not set to an instance of an object* when the Send() method is called because it doesn't have access to ContactModel input in MessagesPage above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# referencing a variable from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301197/c-sharp-referencing-a-variable-from-another-method)

Comment: Make it a field in the class instead of a local variable in the constructor.
And please remove the "Java" tag; this is not Java.

Comment: @Sinatr If it helps, Send() is actually triggered by the enter key on the XAML. I have public ICommand SendCommand => new Command(Send); in my code behind. In your link, Method2 isn't actually an ICommand.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `ConversationPartner` as a class level variable, not inside of of a specific method.  This will make it available throughout your class

```
ContactModel ConversationPartner;

public MessagesPage(ContactModel input)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
   ConversationsList = new ObservableCollection<ConversationModel>();
       
   ConversationPartner = input;
   ...
}
```

Comment: I specifically want to use the input which was passed to the MessagesPage method in the Send() method, though. Would your answer also pass the value of input to the Send() method?

Comment: it stores the `input` parameter in the `ConversationParter` variable, which can then e used from anywhere in the class, including `Send`